GIT LFS (git-lfs) errors when building from Jenkins
I can't successfully checkout large code files from GIT when using Jenkins.  I have verified on my agent machine that I can pull the entire GIT repository and build.  I previously installed GIT-LFS on the agent machine.  So, it's definitely limited to building using Jenkins.
I have also verified I can have a pipeline that pulls the code from git, and successfully builds as long as git-lfs is not used.
The error I am getting in the console window is:
stderr: git-lfs filter-process: line 1: git-lfs: command not found

I have found this StackOverflow article and tried the ideas in it to no avail:
Git LFS setup in jenkins
I can no longer find the reference, but I did see mention that the Jenkins agent might be looking for git-lfs in a particular place and not finding it. That might explain why I can do a git clone, git pull, etc. from a command window on the agent machine with no problems?
Below I have pasted the pipeline script I am using.  As you can see from commented out code, I have tried various combinations.  For full disclosure, I believe the git-lfs plugin was installed, but I don't have administrator rights to say that 100%.  I would have thought I would get a different error if it were not installed, but is there a way to verify?  I also saw mention that it should be possible to do all this w/o the plugin.
Any ideas?  Thanks!
pipeline {
agent { label 'WindowsFoo' }//any
tools {
    msbuild 'MSBuild 2022' // I don't believe this is used!
}

stages {
    stage ('Clean workspace') {
          steps {
            // Clean before build
            cleanWs()  // 
            // cleanWs fails if ANY console window is open or windows explorer open to the repository  
             
          }
        }
        
    stage('Checkout') {
        steps {

                 echo 'checkout'
                
                
                    script 
                    {
                    
                        git credentialsId: 'Foo_ID', url: 'https://github.com/Foo/Foo-software.git'
                        
                       
                         
                         checkout([
                $class: 'GitSCM',
                branches: [[name: '*/master']],
                doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                extensions: [[$class: 'GitLFSPull']],   //extensions: [lfs()],
                submoduleCfg: [],
                userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/Foo/Foo-software.git']]
                      ])  
                      
                    }                   
        }
    }

}

}
FWIW, the agent machine is a Windows 10 machine.

You could try adding a sh 'git lfs --version' step before the checkout and see if that works.

Thanks for the comment @Iterokun   I couldn't get "bat git lfs --version" working at first. I believe the line: git credentialsId: 'FooGIT_ID', url: 'https://github.com/Foo/Foo-software.git' was actually failing and preventing the rest of the pipeline working. I removed this, and made some other tweeks and got things working!  At least the checkout part .... :)

I needed to do several things to get git-lfs working.  Here I post an updated script file for others who may be struggling.  I'm new to Jenkins and msbuild and I do find them annoying to say the least! There are quite a few "gotchas". As an example. It looks like your GIT repo needs a "master" branch.  Jenkins gives an error if there isn't one. As another, cleanWs won't work if a command window and/or windows explorer open to the workspace. Makes sense I suppose, but the error message is very cryptic.  Here is my new script file:
     pipeline {
    agent { label 'WindowsFoo' }
    tools {
        msbuild 'MSBuild 2022'  // I don't think this is used
    }

    stages {
        stage ('Clean workspace') {
              steps {
                // Clean before build
                cleanWs()  
                // IT fails if ANY console window is open or windows explorer
                
              }
            }
            
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
 //               checkout scm
                     echo 'checkout beginning of method'
                    
                    
                        script 
                        {
                            // doing this credentialsId seems to create a pull?
                            //git credentialsId: 'FooGIT_ID', url: 'https://github.com/Foo/Foo-software.git'
                            echo 'just called git credentials'
                           
                            
                             echo 'call checkout'
                              checkout scmGit(branches: [[name: '*/master']], extensions: [lfs(), checkoutOption(120)], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'FooGIT_ID', url: 'https://github.com/Foo/Foo-software.git']])    
                             
                  }
                    
                    
            }
        }
      
}

           
           
           
        

